# How to get values of multiple hidden input on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get values of any dynamic added hidden input element on change ?

As you can see i dont have access to 1st event

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
```

and i cant add to this event

```
$('input[name="img"]').trigger('change')
```

```js
/* I DONT HAVE ACCESS TO THIS PART OF THE CODE */
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
$('input[name="img"]').val($(this).val());
});
/* */

$('input[name="img"]').on('change', function(){
console.log('changed')
});


$('button').click(function(){

var html = `<input type="text">
 <input type="hidden" name="img">`;
            
$('.single').append(html)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="single">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="hidden" name="img">
</div>
</div>
<button>Add row</button>
```

Comment: The question is weird, inputs type of hidden can't fire keyup, because they're ... well, hidden.

Comment: @Teemu yes i know but i need the value of hidden element whenever is change

Comment: *No inputs* raise the `change` event when you change them via code - as hidden inputs can only be changed via code, it will *never* raise a change event.  (unless one is fired via code)

Comment: If the value of an input is programmatically changed, it doesn't fire any event. A [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) migth detect such a change, I'll make some investigations ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an alternate solution

```js
/* I DONT HAVE ACCESS TO THIS PART OF THE CODE */
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
$('input[name="img"]').val($(this).val());
});
/* WE WONT CHANGE ANYTHING HERE*/

/* JUST ADD THIS FUNCTION */
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(){
$('input[name="img"]').trigger('change')
});
/* THIS WILL MAKE SURE THE INPUT IS TRIGGERED CHANGE */

$('input[name="img"]').on('change', function(){
console.log('changed')
});


$('button').click(function(){

var html = `<input type="text">
 <input type="hidden" name="img">`;
            
$('.single').append(html)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="single">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="hidden" name="img">
</div>
</div>
<button>Add row</button>
```

Do let me know if this helps